# How do I correctly set MYPYPATH to pick up stubs for mypy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy

I can't for the life of me get MyPy to find stubs that aren't colocated with their source code. Here's the structure I have for my project:

```
trymypy/
|- stubs/
|  \- foo.pyi
|- __init__.py
|- usefoo.py
\- foo.py
```

```py
# foo.py
def foofunc(x):
    return str(x)
```

```py
# usefoo.py
from trymypy.foo import foofunc

print(foofunc(5) + 5)
```

```py
# stubs/foo.pyi
def foofunc(x: int) -> str: ...
```

I have set the `MYPYPATH` environment variable to `/full/path/to/trymypy/stubs`, so that MyPy should look inside the `stubs` directory for my `.pyi` files.

This should not pass typechecking. MyPy should flag the error as such:

```
../trymypy/usefoo.py:3: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("str" and "int")
```

Instead, MyPy does not flag any errors, because it is not reading the stub file. If I move the stub file `foo.pyi` to the root project of the directory, colocated with `foo.py`, it correctly flags, which indicates to me that the `MYPYPATH` isn't getting picked up, or isn't being defined correctly.

I have also tried setting `mypy_path` in a config file `mypy.ini`:

```
[mypy]
python_version = 3.7
mypy_path = /full/path/to/trymypy/stubs
```

Other config options in `mypy.ini` do get picked up (e.g. `python_version`), so MyPy is seeing the file and reading it.

Totally stumped here. This is a (very) simple example that seems like it should be working as documented by MyPy. I've run out of variables to experiment on to get it working.

I am using Python 3.7 and working in a virtual environment that has only mypy installed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Long story short: rather then having a separate 'stubs' directory, you probably want to move your `foo.pyi` file into the top-level `trymypy` folder, alongside `foo.py`.

---

Long story long, there are currently two problems with your setup.

The first problem is that the folder structure of your stubs need to mirror the way the underlying code is structured. So since you want to do `from trymypy.foo import blah`, you need to adjust your folder structure to look like this:

```
trymypy/
|- stubs/
|  |- trymypy/
|  |  |- __init__.pyi
|  \  \- foo.pyi
|- __init__.py
|- usefoo.py
\- foo.py
```

You should continue setting the mypypath to point to `trymypy/stubs`. You can use either an absolute or a relative path.

The bigger second problem is that your stubs may end up being shadowed and ignored depending on how exactly you're invoking mypy. For example, if you run `mypy -p trymypy` from outside of the `trymypy` folder, mypy will start by parsing every `trymypy` and the two submodules it directly contains (`trymypy.__init__`, `trymypy.usefoo`, and `trymypy.foo`).

And once `trymypy.foo` is loaded, mypy will not bother trying to re-load it again, which means it never bothers checking the stubs you specified.

But if you try type-checking individual files (e.g. `mypy -m trymypy.usefoo`, `mypy -p trymypy.usefoo`), mypy won't try loading everything inside `trymypy`, which means it can find the stubs using the typical [import resolution rules](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/running_mypy.html#mapping-file-paths-to-modules).

You can confirm the behavior of all of this yourself by passing in the `-v` flag, which runs mypy in verbose mode and print out exactly what gets loaded. Be sure to delete the `.mypy_cache` directory before each run.

Note: I actually honestly have no idea whether this difference in behavior is intentional or a bug in mypy. The import rules are pretty nuanced.

---

The fix is thankfully straightforward though: just move your `foo.pyi` file into the top-level `trymypy` folder like so:

```
trymypy/
|- __init__.py
|- usefoo.py
|- foo.py
\- foo.pyi
```

Now, no matter what gets imported in what order, mypy will always find `foo.py` and `foo.pyi` at the same time, since both files are located in the same directory. And whenever a `py` and `pyi` file are located within the same directory, the `pyi` file always wins out (and the py file is ignored).

---

You may perhaps have two follow-up questions regarding this new folder structure:

1. Is there a way to type-check the contents of `foo.py` using the type hints present in `foo.pyi`?

   The answer is no, there currently is not a way. If you have `foo.pyi` present, the body of `foo.py` is essentially ignored altogether by mypy. There is somebody interested in [adding support for this feature](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/5028) though, so you could perhaps subscribe to the linked Github issue for updates.
2. Create a separate "stubs" folder ended up not being useful here. So when *is* it useful?

   The answer is that it's primarily useful when you want to add stubs for third party libraries. I actually don't have a lot of experience with the "add stubs for your own code" workflow, but my understanding is that such stubs are usually "inlined" in the manner described above.

Comment: It's funny, I was just creating this toy example because what I really wanted to do was add stubs for third party libraries, and this was a sandbox for that. I suppose I wouldn't usually even bother having a stub file for my own source code—since I can annotate my own code anyway—so it's not too problematic to not be able to put the stubs in a separate directory.

Comment: It would be nice if someone edited this answer with the perspective (revealed in the comments) that what we really want to do is provide type stubs in our own project for a 3rd party library. The information is there - it's just presented in a confusing way because the question's intention was unclear.